# Get Option HTML by it's value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How we can get the option HTML in jquery by it's value in jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<select multiple="" style="width: 147px;" id="list" name="list" class="list_class">
  <option value="21">A</option>
  <option value="22">B</option>
  <option value="23">C</option>
  <option value="24">D</option>
  <option value="2">E</option>
</select>
```

**Array**

```
var id_arry = ['21','24','2'];
```

I have this array that have some values related to values in the drop down. Now i want to get all the options that matches the value in dropdown HTML
like

```
<option value="21">A</option><option value="24">D</option> <option value="2">E</option>
```

This is the final out put i want from the drop-down.Kindly help me in this

I want to add those options html in this dropdown:

```
<select multiple="" style="width: 147px;" id="list" name="list1" class="list_class">

</select>
```

Comment: do you want to create a new select with those options or... ?

Comment: yes i want to create new select from these options

Comment: Possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Back up a step – do you really want to *grab an HTML string*, or do you actually want to e.g. make a new dropdown with just those options (in which case grabbing the HTML string isn't the best way to do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is using [**join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
var id_arry = ['21', '24', '2'];
$("#list").val(id_arry.join(',').split(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" style="width: 147px;" id="list" name="list" class="list_class">
  <option value="21">A</option>
  <option value="22">B</option>
  <option value="23">C</option>
  <option value="24">D</option>
  <option value="2">E</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i want the option html

Comment: You can use it as you like e.g. `$("#list option:selected");`

Comment: these options are not selected on the page

Comment: the values are not selected in the first dropdown .the values are in the aarray now from that array i want to get the options and then append it to the other dropdown on click of append

Comment: this example is very good but the issue is options are not selected

Comment: This is very simle to solve. Take a look here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3g34m94r/)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
var id_arry = ['21','24','2'];

var optionMatches = $('#list option').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).val(), id_arry);
});
```

Breaking it down:

- `$('#list option')` - returns *all* of the options in the select list with ID "list"
- [`.filter(callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) - a simple filter function -- the callback decides whether the option makes it into the final list
- [`$.inArray($(this).val(), id_arry)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) - checks if the current option value is in the array `id_arry`

After studying your example, it looks like you'll first want to obtain the **selected** options from your multi-select drop-down list to build your `id_arry`, which is very easy:

```
var id_arry = $('#list').val();
```

Once you have these and the `optionMatches` array of elements, you can clone them over to a new drop-down:

```
optionMatches.clone().appendTo('#otherSelect');
```

Comment: @Lix: I appreciate the help :) I did roll back though as the `filter` method is jQuery's, not the native array filter method.

Comment: i want the options html from the dropdown so that i can use that as a option to other drop down

Comment: the values are not selected in the first dropdown .the values are in the aarray now from that array i want to get the options and then append it to the other dropdown on click of append

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to target elements with a specific attribute value:

```
$( "option[value='21']" )
```

Using this selector and a simple loop, you can extract all the elements you need:

```
var elements = [];
var id_array = ['21','24','2'];
for ( index in id_array ){
  var elem = $( "option[value='" + id_array[ index ] + "']" );
  if ( elem ) {
    elements.push( elem );
  }
}
```

Your `elements` array now contains all option elements who's values appear in `id_array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id_arr = ['21','24','2'];
var entireHTML = "";
var options = $('select').find('option');
var tempDiv = $('div');

//id_arr = $('select').val(); //Uncomment this line to get value from the select element.

$.each(id_arr, function(index, value){

   entireHTML = "";

    $(options).each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() === value)
        {
            $(this).clone().appendTo(tempDiv);
        }
    });
});
entireHTML = $(tempDiv).html();
```

Since you need the HTML content of the 'option' elements, they're cloned and wrapped in a temporary div so that the inner HTML of that temporary div is copied and appended to our final HTML string.

Check it out for yourself :  [JSFiddle Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/tno7bqww/4/)